# Working with multiple currencies in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project where user adds many products and compare their prices, average price, minimal and many other statistics.

There are two currencies for now, EUR and CZK.

I'm here to ask you for advices - either about performance or a better structuring of my code.

There are for example 10 prices of one product on it's dashboard page. To be able to compute average price, minimal etc, I'm converting all prices to EUR price, then compute the property (AVG,MIN etc) and then show this property in currency which user set. (They can set either EUR, CZK or original currency).

I feel that this is probably too expensive (according to performance) but I can't figure out a better approach.

**Models**

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=(('eur','EUR'),
                                                       ('czk','CZK')))
    special_sign = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Currencies"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.shortcut


class Price(models.Model):
    currency = models.ForeignKey('Currency',related_name='prices')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{} {}'.format(self.amount,self.currency)

    def to_eur(self):
        if self.currency.shortcut=='eur':
            return self.amount
        elif self.currency.shortcut=='czk':
            return Exchange.objects.first().czk_to_eur(self.amount)

    def to_czk(self):
        if self.currency.shortcut == 'czk':
            return self.amount
        elif self.currency.shortcut == 'eur':
            return Exchange.objects.first().eur_to_czk(self.amount)

    @property
    def eur_price(self):
        if self.currency.shortcut=='eur':
            return self.amount
        elif self.currency.shortcut=='czk':
            return self.to_eur()

    @property
    def czk_price(self):
        cents = decimal.Decimal('01')
        if self.currency.shortcut == 'czk':
            return (self.amount).quantize(cents, decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
        elif self.currency.shortcut == 'eur':
            return self.to_czk()

    @property
    def pref_currency_amount(self):
        pref_currency = self.scan.occurence.product.user.userprofile.preferred_currency
        if pref_currency:
            if pref_currency.shortcut == 'czk':
                return self.czk_price
            else: return self.eur_price
        return self.amount

    @property
    def pref_currency_string(self):
        pref_currency = self.scan.occurence.product.user.userprofile.preferred_currency
        # return pref_currency.shortcut
        if pref_currency:
            if pref_currency.shortcut.lower() == 'czk':
                return u'{} {}'.format(self.czk_price, pref_currency.shortcut)
            else:
                return u'{} {}'.format(self.eur_price, pref_currency.special_sign)
        return u'{} {}'.format(self.amount,self.currency.special_sign)


    def get_price(self,currency):
        if currency=='eur':
            return self.eur_price
        elif currency=='czk':
            return self.czk_price

    def get_exchanged_price_string(self):
        if self.currency.shortcut=='czk':
            return u'{} {}'.format(Exchange.czk_to_eur(self.amount),u'€')
        else:
            return u'{} {}'.format(Exchange.eur_to_czk(self.amount),'CZK')

    def get_original_price_string(self):
        if self.currency.shortcut=='czk':
            return u'{} {}'.format(self.amount,u'€')
        else:
            return u'{} {}'.format(Exchange.eur_to_czk(self.amount),'CZK')
```

## SHORTEN MODEL

```
class Occurence(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='occurences', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    currency = models.ForeignKey('Currency',related_name='occurences')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name='occurences', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def stats_get_min_price(self):
        scan = self.get_min_scan()
        if scan:
            price = scan.price.eur_price
        else:
            price = None
        return {'price': price,
                'xml_tag': '<min_price>',
                'xml_close_tag': '</min_price>',
                'label': 'Min'}

    def stats_get_avg_price(self):
        prices = [x.price for x in self.scans.all() if x.price]
        if prices:
            price = math_ops.round_eur(decimal.Decimal(sum([x.eur_price for x in prices]) / len(prices), 2))
        else:
            price = None

        preferred_currency = self.product.user.userprofile.preferred_currency

        if preferred_currency:
            if preferred_currency.shortcut == 'czk':
                amount = Exchange.eur_to_czk(price)
                pref_currency_string = '{} CZK'.format(amount)
                pref_currency_amount = amount
            else:
                amount = price
                pref_currency_string = u'{} €'.format(amount)
                pref_currency_amount = amount
        else:
            if self.currency.shortcut == 'czk':
                amount = Exchange.eur_to_czk(price)
                pref_currency_string = '{} CZK'.format(amount)
                pref_currency_amount = amount
            else:
                amount = price
                pref_currency_string = u'{} €'.format(amount)
                pref_currency_amount = amount


        return {'price': price,
                'pref_currency_string':pref_currency_string,
                'pref_currency_amount':pref_currency_amount,
                'xml_tag': '<average_price>',
                'xml_close_tag': '</average_price>',
                'label': 'AVG'}
```

**THEN IN TEMPLATES (OR TABLES)**

```
class OccurencesTable(tables.Table):
    avg_price = tables.columns.TemplateColumn("""{{ record.stats_get_avg_price.pref_currency_string }}""",accessor='stats_get_avg_price.price', verbose_name='AVG price')
    last_scan_price = tables.columns.TemplateColumn("""{{ record.get_last_scan.price.pref_currency_string }} """,accessor='get_last_scan.price.amount', verbose_name='Last scan price')
    difference = tables.columns.TemplateColumn("""{% load static %}{% with diff=record.stats_get_difference_for_two_last_scans.percent %}
                {% if diff > 0 %}+{% endif %}{{ diff }} % <img style="height: 15px" src="{% if diff < 0 %}{% static "img/icons/arrow-trend-minus.png" %}{% elif diff == 0 %}{% static "img/icons/arrow-trend-normal.png" %}{% else %}{% static "img/icons/arrow-trend-plus.png" %}{% endif %}">
                {% endwith %}""",verbose_name='Difference')
```

I would like to hear your thoughs, should I do something better?